# SQL Server issue with ISDATE('3/31/019')

Tags: sql, sql-server

I found the following issue when I try to valid the following date

ISDATE('3/31/019') this return 1, but is not a valid date, when you try to convert(date, '3/31/019') you will get an error

[image]

[image]

I expect ISDATE('3/31/019') return distinct 1

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/ydC5jkii

Comment: I tend to use try_convert(date, ...)  Take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/AbYDWQeQ

Comment: Don't use `ISDATE` is the solution, just like you shouldn't use `ISNUMERIC`; use `TRY_CONVERT`/`TRY_CAST`.

Comment: Also [please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 4):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql) states (my added emphasis):

> Returns 1 if the expression is a valid **datetime** value; otherwise, 0.

So if you run:

```
SELECT convert(datetime, '3/31/019');
```

The result with session setting `SET DATEFMT mdy` succeedes with value '2019-03-31 00:00:00.000'.

Instead of `ISDATE`, use `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_CAST` to determine if the expression can be converted to a date. The result will be `NULL` if not convertable.

Answer (score 2):

According to [ISDATE documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isdate-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

> Returns 1 if the expression is a valid **datetime** value; otherwise,
> 0.

While you are trying to convert to **date** format.

The below query runs without issue
`SELECT CONVERT(datetime, '3/31/019')`